# python c api. Call python function with multiple outputs using cpp(python c api)

Tags: python, c, api

I would like to call a python function that has multiple outputs from C++.
Currently i am able to call a python function (from cpp)that outputs only 1 value. How can i modify my code in order to be able to receive multiple outputs from python on the cpp side

python code:

```
def add(a, b):
x = (a+b)
return x
```

cpp code:

```
Py_Initialize();


PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;

pName = PyString_FromString("myFunc");

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add");
pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);

pValue = PyFloat_FromDouble(11+i);

PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);


PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);


double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pResult);
cout << "Value of variable i is: " << result <<endl;
}
```

I would like to modify my python function to return 2 outputs i.e.:

```
import numpy as np 

def add(a, b):
x = (a+b)
return np.sqrt(x),x
```

I can not print the 2 outputsfrom python in cpp. How should i modify my cpp code to print the 2 outputs from python

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you mean:  Python functions can only return one thing.  If you mean like `x, y = f()`, f is returning a tuple, so you will have to inspect the tuple using the C API.

Comment: i have modified the question to what i would like to do

Comment: The second Python code _doesn't_ return two outputs. It actually returns a single object of type `tuple`, so your C++ code should be dealing with tuples instead of `PyFloat_AsDouble`.

Comment: I have tried using PyTuple_GetItem but i couldn't access the entries inside. Is there any available tutorial to see how is done?